# One big asset file or many small asset files?

Tags: c++, assets, asset-management

I'm working on a game and I'm wondering if it is better for performance and memory usage to have one large file containing all my assets (the assets are in a custom format) with a look up table at the front telling the location of the asset in the file or is it better to have each asset in its own file?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: Personally I would suggest grouping them into logical pieces. Assets that are always loaded together should be grouped in one file. For general assets for global availability I'd probably go fo the one big library style, but I think you should profile your solutions and then choose whatever was more efficient.

Comment: Many games use compressed archives and mount them using a virtual file system which transparently fetches files from the compressed archive.